# EDI XML To XML transformation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, edi, edifabric

I have the following XML that I transformed using EDIFabric from and EDI file to XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<M_856 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="www.edifabric.com/x12">
    <S_N3>
        <D_166_1>UNION SQUARE IND PK</D_166_1>
        <D_166_2>909 KATIE COURT</D_166_2>
    </S_N3>
    <S_N4>
        <D_19_1>Harrisburg</D_19_1>
        <D_156_2>PA</D_156_2>
        <D_116_3>17109</D_116_3>
        <D_26_4>US</D_26_4>
    </S_N4>        
    <S_SE>
        <D_96_1>22</D_96_1>
        <D_329_2>1845</D_329_2>
    </S_SE>
</M_856>
```

I would like to extract all S_N4 nodes as follows:

```
<City>Harrisburg</City>
<State>PA</State>
<PostalCode>17109</PostalCode>
<Country>US</Country>
```

what is the XSLT transformation required?

Answer (score 0):

The below would do, rename Root to whatever your root is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl s0" version="1.0" xmlns:s0="www.edifabric.com/x12">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:M_856" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/s0:M_856">
    <Root>
      <City>
        <xsl:value-of select="s0:S_N4/s0:D_19_1/text()" />
      </City>
      <State>
        <xsl:value-of select="s0:S_N4/s0:D_156_2/text()" />
      </State>
      <PostalCode>
        <xsl:value-of select="s0:S_N4/s0:D_116_3/text()" />
      </PostalCode>
      <Country>
        <xsl:value-of select="s0:S_N4/s0:D_26_4/text()" />
      </Country>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why do you think you need the 1st template?

Comment: To apply the second template :) Not really necessary just a matter of preference.